# Javascript ViewModel Initialisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm creating an SPA, I'm using knockout js for the view model stuff. I'm also using Sammy js for the routing and naviagtion.

I used learn.knoutoutjs.com for the starters of how to create an SPA. In this they have the main view model as a function:

```
function mainViewModel() {
    // insert other view models in here

    Sammy(function () {
       // initialise Sammy routes here
    });
}
```

I'm using an object rather than a function in my code:

```
var mainViewModel = {
    // insert other view models in here
}
```

I'm doing it this way out of personal preference. `ko.applyBindings` works a treat with this, and I've got a view model in a different file getting attached in the `mainViewModel` then it is binded by knockout.

However, when dealing with a function, it gets initialised and ran, so `Sammy(function () {})` gets fired. Using the `var` method, it doesn't, how do I get it to do this, because inside the `Sammy(function () {})` it requires the use of the `mainViewModel` but obviously it hasn't been initialised when the page is loaded up.

How do I put `Sammy` in the `var` method and get it to initialise?

I have this code:

```
var personViewModel = {
   init: function () {
       this.person = ko.observable(new this.personModel({firstname:"callum", lastname:"linington"}));
   },
   personModel: function (data) {
       var self = this;
       self.firstname = ko.observable(data.firstname);
       self.lastname = ko.observable(data.lastname);

       self.fullname = ko.computed(function () {
            return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
       }, this);
   },
   person: new Object()
};
```

then:

```
var mainViewModel = {
   init: function () { 
     // do sammy stuff
   },
   personViewModel: personViewModel.init()
}

ko.applyBindings(mainViewModel.init());
```

but it is saying that:

> Uncaught TypeError: Unable to parse bindings. Bindings value: with:
>   $root.personViewModel.person Message: Cannot read property
>   'personViewModel' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var mainViewModel = {        

            init : function(){    
                    Sammy(function () {
                           // initialise Sammy routes here
                    });
              },    
             anotherMethod1 : function(){},

             anotherMethod2 : function(){}

    }

    mainViewModel.init();
```

Comment: ummm, quick question, does the `anotherMethod1` get initialise with that? or do they have to be initialised with in the `init` function because i've given this a go, and it comes back with there is no instance!