# Knockout Tutorial Mystery Changing ViewModels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

If you navigate to the [WebMail Tutorial here](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail) you'll be able to see the tutorial on how to create an SPA (single page application).

If you skip to step 4, scroll down the info box (top left box) you can click `Help it's not working` button at the bottom and it will place all the code for you.

My question, is that when a mail item gets clicked, how does it change the view? I'm missing something, blatently obvious, but can't put my finger on it.

I need to know because I want to apply this to a SPA, where I can click on a link down the left hand side menu, and change the main content to something else!

Thanks :)

Comment: It uses sammyJS to load correct model dependeing on query string

Comment: Sorry, I kind of gathered that in the tutorial.... I need specifics to where it tells the html to not display and to show the correct ones, I need a full answer detailing exactly how it is done, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need specifics to where it tells the html to not display and to
>   show the correct ones

When navigating a folder it will first clear the mail data `self.chosenMailData(null);`

```
// Client-side routes    
Sammy(function () {
    this.get('#:folder', function () {
        self.chosenFolderId(this.params.folder);
        self.chosenMailData(null);
        $.get("/mail", { folder: this.params.folder }, self.chosenFolderData);
    });

    this.get('#:folder/:mailId', function () {
        self.chosenFolderId(this.params.folder);
        self.chosenFolderData(null);
        $.get("/mail", { mailId: this.params.mailId }, self.chosenMailData);
    });

    this.get('', function () { this.app.runRoute('get', '#Inbox') });
}).run();
```

Here is a small demo app I did how you can create a SPA engine using SammyJS
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap.Demo

Comment: So, if I wanted to apply this to an SPA with multiple view models, how would I go about applying this technique? See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890323/javascript-viewmodel-initialisation)

Comment: Very useful link, shame my server side is going to be all in javascript using node js!

Comment: Its 95% JS only, check the MasterViewModel.js most of the magic is done there, https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap.Demo/blob/master/Knockout.Bootstrap.Demo.Web/Scripts/site/models/Master/MasterViewModel.js